# Ajax request - timeout error/warning

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout

I have this function and it works fine most of the times, but if something irregular happens, the client will not know why the loading gif is always showing .

I would like to know if I can define a 20 second timeout, and if the ajax request is unsuccessful  the loading gif disappears and shows an error like "connection lost" or something similar:

```
function ajaxrequest(){
                var params = [];
                for (var i=0; i < submit.length; i++) {
                    var ele = submit[i];
                    params[i] = ele + '=' + $('#' + ele).attr('value');
                }
                params = params.join('&');
                $(".agendarleft").html("<center><img src='skins/{VAL_SKIN}/styleImages/iloading.gif'></center>");
                $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ajaxload/como.php",
                data: params,
                success: function() {
                $(".agendarleft").html("<center><div style='height:50px'><h2>Enviado! Seremos breves na resposta.</h2></div></center><br/><img src='../skins/Sandbox_Light/styleImages/after1.jpg'/></center>");
                }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check timeout parameter here

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/u3f9C/183/

If you changed timeout to 1000 you will see error . For now it should show timeout as timeout value is really low and it times out even before it tried to connect to url.

Comment: How is the error parameter handled? When does it occur? Should i use "timeout" or "error"?

Comment: In your example above, the spinner would endlessly spin no matter why the request failed (500 or whatever). If this is the case, it's not really a matter of timeout, but of error handling in general, as I mentioned in my answer. If you're server is not responsive, and you want to manually timeout the request after a certain time, Sones Dabhis answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: The timeout setting is just telling it how long you want the timeout to be.  Then you would handle the timeout in your error callback, so you would be using both.

Comment: As for the spinner, use the complete callback when setting up the ajax call to hide the spinner, as it is always called.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an error callback, like this:

```
$.ajax({}).error(function(){ // remove spinner or do something else });
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Or in the style of your request above:

```
$.ajax({error: function() {}, success: function() {} });
```